# Xml deserialization of a list which skips invalid elements?

Tags: c#, exception, xml-serialization, generic-list

I have some problems with the de-serialization of a generic list. My class implements the **IXmlSerializable** interface and stores some **MyFilter** objects in a **Filters** property. It contains the following code:

WriteXml:

```cs
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyFilter>));
serializer.Serialize(bodyWriter, Filters.ToList());
```

ReadXml:

```cs
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyFilter>));
Filters = (List<MyFilter>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

There are no problems with the serialization or xml structure itself. The **MyFilter** class also implements the **IXmlSerializable** interface. 
The issue shows up when the xml is deserialized: at runtime, the deserialization of some **MyFilter** objects may fail when the filter relies on data which is currently not available. This is "works as designed" but of course kills the whole process with an exception.

So my question is: How can I achieve skipping the **MyFilter** objects throwing an exception during their deserialization? 
 I guess I have to deserialize the collection manually, catch the exception and just go on with the next element. Is this a good approach? And how can it be done?

Comment: Is MyFilter doing anything beyond setting the member at deserialization time?  It sounds like you need to decouple the get/set logic from whatever else you're doing.

Comment: No, it just stores some data for serialization. What do you mean with "decouple the get/set logic"? I did not get that, sorry.

Comment: Specifically, I was referring to this: "...the deserialization of some MyFilter objects may fail when the filter relies on data which is currently not available."  Do you mean, for example, an `int` that is non-existent in the XML data?

Comment: The MyFilter object contains a reference to a particular value. The value is part of the runtime data at serialization time. But on deserialization it may not exist anymore. Then, the deserialization of this single MyFilter object throws an exception.

Comment: Sorry, forgot this to mention:  The MyFilter objects are serialized as part of a more complex class FilterList holding a list of them. When a FilterList object is deserialized, it should somehow skip these invalids list items.

Comment: What exactly makes them invalid?

Comment: The system knows a priori which values are available - say, depending on the kind of document opened. This is not exactly how it works, but the analogy should be sufficient. The MyFilter und FilterList objects are used to store and restore data from the last session. Now, when a different kind of document is loaded, the set of available values may have changed. Then, the value inside the MyFilter object is invalid because there is no equivalent in the system data. The important thing is: the system cannot ensure that the deserialized value currently exists.

Comment: Re: *the system knows*.  based on this description, you are mixing de-serialization (which is a re-animation of state) with object retrieval. They are not the same and your inappropriate mixing of them seems to be what is causing your problem. A better approach is to de-couple the two.  Allow your object to  deserialize itself without referencing external state that "the system knows" about.  Then add another method to your object to  validate or reduce the de-serialized state to conform to whatever requirements your system has.